# PHP - any easy way to make this math equation?

Tags: php, for-loop, math

I have a game where you can buy defence, but my math doesn't add up and I don't understand how I am suppossed to solve it.

```
Amount from   amount to       Price pr
0             10 000          $1 500 
10 000        50 000          $2 500
50 000        1 000 000       $3 000
1 000 000     5 000 000       $5 000
5 000 000     inf             $10 000

$fp_from[0] = 0;
$fp_to[0] = 10000;

$fp_from[1] = $fp_to[0];
$fp_to[1] = 50000;

$fp_from[2] = $fp_to[1];
$fp_to[2] = 1000000;

$fp_from[3] = $fp_to[2];
$fp_to[3] = 5000000;

$fp_from[4] = $fp_to[3];
$fp_to[4] = INF;

$price_pr[0] = 1500;
$price_pr[1] = 2500;
$price_pr[2] = 3000;
$price_pr[3] = 5000;
$price_pr[4] = 10000;
```

For now I just have this for loop to get the price:

```
for($k = 0; $k < count($fp_from); $k++){
    if($defence >= $fp_from[$k] && $defence <= $fp_to[$k]){
        $my_price_pr = $price_pr[$k];
    }
}
```

But say I have 1 000 defence, and buy 10 000 I will have 11 000. But the price for the 10 000 is only 1 500 pr, but I want the amount up to 10 000 to be 1 500, and over be 2 500. The price that I get is 15 000 000 ( 10 000 * 1 500 ), but the price I want is 16 000 000 ( 13 500 000 + 2 500 000 ).

This is my whole buying script

```
if(isset($_POST['post'])){
    if(isset($_POST['amount'])){
        $amount = remove_space($_POST['amount']);
        
        $defence = $AS_session_row['AS_def'];
        $my_price_pr = 0;
        $money = 100000000; // 100 000 000

        for($k = 0; $k < count($fp_from); $k++){
            if($defence >= $fp_from[$k] && $defence <= $fp_to[$k]){
                $my_price_pr = $price_pr[$k];
            }
        }
        
        if(is_numeric($amount) && $amount > 0){
            if($my_price_pr * $amount <= $money){
                $total_price = $my_price_pr * $amount;
                
                give_fp($amount, $_SESSION['ID'], $pdo);
                take_money($_SESSION['ID'], $total_price, $pdo);
                
                echo success_msg("FP was bought");
            } else {
                echo error_msg("Not enough money");
            }
        } else {
            echo fail_msg("Wrong input");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're only buying 10000 why should the price not be 1500000? Why does the starting amount matter?

Comment: Because, then you can simply buy 5 000 000 when you have 0 defence and the price pr would only be 1 500.

Comment: Weird pricing. If I buy 2 milk and have none at home I pay 1500, but if I have 1 at home the first milk costs 1500, but the second 2500?

Comment: I could make it a static price-tag. But since it's for a game, and as more you grow the more money you get, you will get immortal if the price doesn't expand as you get more :/

Comment: So advancing is being punished? If that's the case, rethink your strategy.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest in looking into foreach loop https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php they are quite useful when dealing with arrays.

EDIT: You need to increment the total_price while looping through prices as well take into consideration defense level before and after it is bought. Afterwards you can use your checks if the person has enough money and so on...

```
$defence = 0;
$my_price_pr = 0;

$fp_from[0] = 0;
$fp_to[0] = 10000;

$fp_from[1] = $fp_to[0];
$fp_to[1] = 50000;

$fp_from[2] = $fp_to[1];
$fp_to[2] = 1000000;

$fp_from[3] = $fp_to[2];
$fp_to[3] = 5000000;

$fp_from[4] = $fp_to[3];
$fp_to[4] = INF;

$price_pr[0] = 1500;
$price_pr[1] = 2500;
$price_pr[2] = 3000;
$price_pr[3] = 5000;
$price_pr[4] = 10000;


$total_price = 0;

$amount = 11000;

$my_price_pr = 0;



$defenceAfterBuying = $defence + $amount;

foreach ($price_pr as $key => $value) {
    for ($i=$defence; $i <= $defenceAfterBuying; $i++) { 
        if ($i > $fp_from[$key] && $i <= $fp_to[$key]) {
            $total_price += $price_pr[$key];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The for-loop is working, but the math doesn't add up if you see in my example, simply because I don't know how to write the math equation.

Comment: Here is the solution with foreach

Comment: Not really, because when I have 0 defence, and buy 11 000 defence, the total price gets to 16 500 000 and not 17 500 000

Comment: So maybe issue is not at price setting as this script works if you change defence to 9000 $my_price is 1.5k if you change it to 11000 price is 2.5k as it supposed to be. So maybe you have an issue with the buying script ?

Comment: I just added the whole script

Comment: Maybe it's my explenation that is wrong. But if I have 9000 defence, I buy 2000, then the 1000 up to 10 000 should be 1 500, and the rest of the 2000, should be 2 500. So 1 000 points should cost 1 500 pr, and 1 000 should cost 2 500.